# Forgot Password code: Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm building an iOS app and I need to provide a forgot password function. I have a db that stores registered users and their details(userArray). I have searched by email inputed so, ***how do I do a UIAlert that shows the found password???*** below is code I tried but my if condition is wrong.

[self.theuser valueForKey:@"password"] is the retrieved password from the database and its a string.

```
   - (IBAction)ForgotPassword:(id)sender {


    if ([[self.theuser valueForKey:@"password"] > 0 ]) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Success"
                                                       message: @"Your Password is:"
                                                      delegate: self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Comment: Please see "[Why is storing a plain-text password bad?](http://plaintextoffenders.com/faq/devs)" on plaintextoffenders.com.

Comment: The point made by @ruakh cannot be stressed strongly enough.  It's almost always a bad idea to store passwords in plaintext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
@"Your Password is:"
```

to:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Password is: %@", [self.theuser valueForKey:@"password"]]
```

You can also change this:

```
 if ([[self.theuser valueForKey:@"password"] > 0 ]) {
```

to this:

```
 if ([self.theuser valueForKey:@"password"]) {
```

If it didn't exist, it would count as "false".  Any other value is "true".

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that the length of the string is higher than 0, because using this:

```
 if ([self.theuser valueForKey:@"password"])
```

will always return **true** if the value is other than **nil**, meaning if you server code returns that the value of password is **""** (two quote marks with no space in between) then the app will recognize that the value is **not nil** and display an alert with no text in it

So the final code should look something like this:

```
- (IBAction)ForgotPassword:(id)sender {

    NSString *retrievedPassword = [self.theuser valueForKey:@"password"];

    if ( retrievedPassword.length > 0) {
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your password is: %@", retrievedPassword];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Success"
                                                       message: message
                                                      delegate: self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to allocate the retrieved data to a label?? the label is declared as passwordLabel

Comment: sure, just substitute the alert code inside the **if** for `passwordLabel.text = message;`